# Do Image Gallery's images have an ID?

Tags: java, android, image-gallery

I have a List that contains images(ID's), but I also want the user to load his own images so they're added to the app and saved into the List. Now, as far as I can see the only way of doing so is getting the Bitmap of the images, but I need an int.

Is there any method to get the ID of an Image Gallery's image?

(When I say Image Gallery I mean the images that the user has in his SD Card)

Comment: "*... but I need an `int`.*" - Why?

Comment: Why do you need an int/id of an image?

Comment: Because the list is made out from ints, I can't add a string or bitmap into a list made out of integers, unless bitmaps are ints capable of being added into a ArrayList<int>. (Edit: The reason why I use a List made out of ints it's because it has the ID's of the images from the drawable folder, but I also want it to contain the images that the user adds from it's phone).

Comment: Well those images are not represented by ints.

Comment: `I have a List that contains images,` No. It's a list of ints you said. The ints are resource ids.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected that, now it says ID's. I still need a way of doing so, if you know how can I do it please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, no, they don't, at least not ID's in the same way as resources ID's work, which means they are probably not numbers and/or don't work in the same way.